# Printing linked List infinite loop C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to print a linked list after having added a node. I have a dummy node to start the list

```
   Node **nodeArray;
    nodeArray = malloc(10 * sizeof(Node *));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        nodeArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(Node));    
    }

    if (userChoice == 'a') 
        add(&nodeArray, setNumber);

void add(Node ***nodeArray, int setNumber) {
        char userString[5];
        printf("Please enter some data: ");
        scanf("%s", userString);

        Node *head = *nodeArray[setNumber];     /* head pointer to first element of array (dummy) */
        Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));   /* new node to be added to array */

        strncpy(newNode->data, userString, sizeof(newNode->data));  /* copies string entered by the user to data field of new node */
        newNode->next = NULL;   /* initializes next field of new node to NULL */

        Node *tmp = head;   /* pointer to head of list */

        while (!tmp->next) {
            tmp->next = newNode;    /* inserts new node into array */
            tmp = newNode;      /* points head to newly added node */
        }

        tmp = head;     /* points tmp back to head of list */

        printf("List is: ");
        while (tmp->next) {
            printf("%s", (tmp->data));
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
}
```

But when I print, I get an infinite loop printing out the data field of the newly added node. Terrible with linked lists....what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. Don't need to tell it like a story. Just present the MCVE because we can read such simple code for ourselves just fine without a block by block explanation. And all in one block so it is easier for anyone to copy to try if desired.

Comment: What is `nodeArray`? Did you mean `Node *head = *Node[setNumber]; ` ?

Comment: See edit for detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (tmp->next) {
   tmp->next = newNode;    /* inserts new node into array */
   tmp = newNode;      /* points head to newly added node */
}
```

In this snippet you're losing the refrence to the next node, and just adding the newNode next to the head. For instance you have the following list:

```
[1]->[2]->[3]
```

And you want to push a new element into that list: [4], what happens when you execute your push function (the snippet above) is:

```
tmp = head; // tmp = [1]
while(tmp->next) {
    tmp->next = newNode; // [1]->next = [4]
    tmp = newNode; // tmp = [4]
}
```

So the next time '(tmp->next)' is evaluated it will be evaluated as: [4]->next and it will be NULL, breaking the loop. Your list will then be:

```
[1]->[4]
```

The other elements are lost because you don't have a reference pointing to them anymore, this is called a memory leak because you won't be able to free them later.

You could write your push function this way:

```
tmp = head;
while(tmp->next)
    tmp = tmp->next;
tmp->next = newNode // Adds new node to the tail of the linked list
```

Comment: Sorry, could you explain that in a little more detail?

Comment: @namarino Of course. This is what's happening in your snippet: for example you have this list [1]->[2]->[3] and you're going to add [4]. So you're setting tmp = [1]. In the first time your loop is executed you're setting tmp->next = newNode, i.e., [1]->next = [4], after that you set tmp = newNode, i. e., tmp = [4]. So the next time it loops it will evaluate [4]->next and not [2]->next as you're expecting. The final list after pushing will be [1]->[4], [2]->[3] are forever lost.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Is it a good idea to make a pointer to my head pointer like I did up there where I said Node *head = *nodeArray[setNumber]; and then Node *tmp = head; or should I just work directly with head?

Comment: Whenever you can use variable names to make the "inner" workings of your code clear you should. In this case you are going to use tmp later and it's being initialised as 'head', IMHO it's a good idea to use it this way.

Answer (score 1):

This is because after this:

```
while (!tmp->next) {
    tmp->next = newNode;    /* inserts new node into array */
    tmp = newNode;      /* points head to newly added node */
}
```

head points to newNode and newNode->next points to newNode.

That's the problem.
Actually the insertion of a newNode is a problem. You will have to change it.

Comment: When does newNode->next point to newNode?  It isn't initialized that way, and this loop appears to only change what head points to.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to add the new Node to the end of your array (aka push).
so try this:

```
Node tmp=head; /* pointer to the head of list */
while (tmp->next) tmp=tmp->next; /* step from Node to Node till the last one */
tmp->next=newNode; /* tell that last one to point to the new Node you created */
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a closed circle link list by this lines:

```
while (!tmp->next) {
    tmp->next = newNode;    /* inserts new node into array */
    tmp = newNode;          /* points head to newly added node */
}
```

so after this actually you get `newNode->next = newNode` which is `tmp->next = tmp.

So instead of this you should do this:

```
while (tmp->next) {
    tmp = tmp->next;    //Find the last node
}
tmp->next = newNode;    //Inserts new node into the end of the array
```

Comment: tmp is a pointer to head. Node *head = *nodeArray[setNumber]; and then Node *tmp = head;